# Search Query in android studio(kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm  currently following a news app tutorial and I have a problem. When I type in a keyword in the edit text widget, articles related to that keyword shows up in the recycler view but when I erase that keyword to type in another keyword, the articles (in the recycler view) from the previous search query doesn't update and even when I exit the search fragment and open it again,The recycler view remains stagnant instead of disappearing. Can anyone please take a look at my code and let me know what I've done wrong. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:
Search Fragment

`class SearchNewsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_search_news) {

```
lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
lateinit var newsAdapter: NewsAdapter
val TAG = "SearchNewsFragment"

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel
    setupRecyclerView()

    newsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putSerializable("article", it)
        }
        findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_searchNewsFragment_to_articleFragment,
            bundle
        )
    }

    var job: Job? = null
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener { editable ->
        job?.cancel()
        job = MainScope().launch {
            delay(SEARCH_NEWS_TIME_DELAY)
            editable?.let {
                if(editable.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                    viewModel.searchNews(editable.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    viewModel.searchNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        when(response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                hideErrorMessage()
                response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                    newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles.toList())
                    val totalPages = newsResponse.totalResults / Constants.QUERY_PAGE_SIZE + 2
                    isLastPage = viewModel.searchNewsPage == totalPages
                    if(isLastPage) {
                        rvSearchNews.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    }
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.message?.let { message ->
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "An error occured: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    showErrorMessage(message)
                }
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                showProgressBar()
            }
        }
    })

    btnRetry.setOnClickListener {
        if (etSearch.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
            viewModel.searchNews(etSearch.text.toString())
        } else {
            hideErrorMessage()
        }
    }
}

private fun hideProgressBar() {
    paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    isLoading = false
}

private fun showProgressBar() {
    paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    isLoading = true
}

private fun hideErrorMessage() {
    itemErrorMessage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    isError = false
}

private fun showErrorMessage(message: String) {
    itemErrorMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    tvErrorMessage.text = message
    isError = true
}

var isError = false
var isLoading = false
var isLastPage = false
var isScrolling = false

val scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
        val firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
        val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount

        val isNoErrors = !isError
        val isNotLoadingAndNotLastPage = !isLoading && !isLastPage
        val isAtLastItem = firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount
        val isNotAtBeginning = firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
        val isTotalMoreThanVisible = totalItemCount >= Constants.QUERY_PAGE_SIZE
        val shouldPaginate = isNoErrors && isNotLoadingAndNotLastPage && isAtLastItem && isNotAtBeginning &&
                isTotalMoreThanVisible && isScrolling
        if(shouldPaginate) {
            viewModel.searchNews(etSearch.text.toString())
            isScrolling = false
        }
    }

    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
            isScrolling = true
        }
    }
}


private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    newsAdapter = NewsAdapter()
    rvSearchNews.apply {
        adapter = newsAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        addOnScrollListener(this@SearchNewsFragment.scrollListener)
    }
}
```

}`

SearchNewsAdapter

```
`class SearchNewsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchNewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {
// Inner class for viewHolder
inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem.url== newItem.url
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

//recyclerViewFunction
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
    return ArticleViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.search_article_preview,parent, false)
    )


}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.size
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val article = differ.currentList[position]
    holder.itemView.apply{
       // Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)
        searchTitle.text = article.title
        setOnClickListener{
            onItemClickListener?.let{
                it(article)
            }
        }

    }
}
//item click listener to single article so that article fragment opens up the webview that shows our items
private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener:(Article) -> Unit){
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
```

}`

NewsViewModel
`class NewsViewModel(
app: Application,
val newsRepository: NewsRepository
) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

```
val breakingNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<NewsResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
var breakingNewsPage = 1
var breakingNewsResponse: NewsResponse? = null

val searchNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<NewsResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
var searchNewsPage = 1
var searchNewsResponse: NewsResponse? = null
var newSearchQuery:String? = null
var oldSearchQuery:String? = null


init {
    getBreakingNews("us")
}

fun getBreakingNews(countryCode: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    safeBreakingNewsCall(countryCode)
}

fun searchNews(searchQuery: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    safeSearchNewsCall(searchQuery)
}

private fun handleBreakingNewsResponse(response: Response<NewsResponse>) : Resource<NewsResponse> {
    if(response.isSuccessful) {
        response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
            breakingNewsPage++
            if(breakingNewsResponse == null) {
                breakingNewsResponse = resultResponse
            } else {
                val oldArticles = breakingNewsResponse?.articles
                val newArticles = resultResponse.articles
                oldArticles?.addAll(newArticles)
            }
            return Resource.Success(breakingNewsResponse ?: resultResponse)
        }
    }
    return Resource.Error(response.message())
}




private fun handleSearchNewsResponse(response: Response<NewsResponse>) : Resource<NewsResponse> {
    if(response.isSuccessful) {
        response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
            if(searchNewsResponse == null || newSearchQuery != oldSearchQuery) {
                searchNewsPage = 1
                oldSearchQuery = newSearchQuery
                searchNewsResponse = resultResponse
            } else {
                searchNewsPage++
                val oldArticles = searchNewsResponse?.articles
                val newArticles = resultResponse.articles
                oldArticles?.addAll(newArticles)
            }
            return Resource.Success(searchNewsResponse ?: resultResponse)
        }
    }
    return Resource.Error(response.message())
}

fun saveArticle(article: Article) = viewModelScope.launch {
    newsRepository.upsert(article)
}

fun getSavedNews() = newsRepository.getSavedNews()

fun deleteArticle(article: Article) = viewModelScope.launch {
    newsRepository.deleteArticle(article)
}

private suspend fun safeSearchNewsCall(searchQuery: String) {
    newSearchQuery = searchQuery
    searchNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())
    try {
        if(hasInternetConnection()) {
            val response = newsRepository.searchNews(searchQuery, searchNewsPage)
            searchNews.postValue(handleSearchNewsResponse(response))
        } else {
            searchNews.postValue(Resource.Error("No internet connection"))
        }
    } catch(t: Throwable) {
        when(t) {
            is IOException -> searchNews.postValue(Resource.Error("Network Failure"))
            else -> searchNews.postValue(Resource.Error("Conversion Error"))
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun safeBreakingNewsCall(countryCode: String) {
    breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())
    try {
        if(hasInternetConnection()) {
            val response = newsRepository.getBreakingNews(countryCode, breakingNewsPage)
            breakingNews.postValue(handleBreakingNewsResponse(response))
        } else {
            breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Error("No internet connection"))
        }
    } catch(t: Throwable) {
        when(t) {
            is IOException -> breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Error("Network Failure"))
            else -> breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Error("Conversion Error"))
        }
    }
}

private fun hasInternetConnection(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = getApplication<NewsApplication>().getSystemService(
        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
    ) as ConnectivityManager
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork) ?: return false
        return when {
            capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
            return when(type) {
                TYPE_WIFI -> true
                TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                else -> false
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

}

`

Comment: If you still have that problem, i had that too and managed to solve that in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74329510/retrofit-responses-keep-the-old-data-and-add-the-new-one-to-that-for-edittext-se)

Answer (score 0):

`if(editable.toString().isNotEmpty()) { viewModel.searchNews(editable.toString()) }`

this line of code prevent the empty query to be processed. So, when you delete everything from the edit text, it will do nothing, hence the result still the same.

> even when I exit the search fragment and open it again,The recycler view remains stagnant instead of disappearing.

The search result is strored on `NewsViewModel` and because the `ViewModel` is initialized on the `NewsActivity`, it tied to the activity lifecycle. Even if you destroy the fragment, the search result (the whole `ViewModel`) will be kept because the activity is still alive. So, when you open back the search Fragment, the `LiveData` will give you the latest value.